# Protect folder in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6

I need a really simple password protection for a certain folder in my MVC-4 application.
By simple I mean: no database validation, no ASP membership, no forms authentication, no OpenID, etc.

There will be only one user allowed to have access to the views in a folder called "Admin": Username "ABV" and password "myPassword". Again: I do not have high security requirements. It's more about keeping users outside who tried to enter certain dialogs by accident.

I was hoping for a way to just bring up the Windows Authentication dialog as soon as I hit the Admin folder the first time.

Some posts on this forum suggest to put this in the web.config:

```
<location path="Admin">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="ABV"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

On my server I added a Windows user called "ABV" with the password mentioned above.

When I try to access a view in the Admin folder, I'm getting a 404 error. No password dialog appeared.

I have also been playing around with the settings of my web server (IIS6), like unchecking "Enable anonymous access". But what ever I did, it didn't help.

I'm sure I missed something obvious and hope that somebody can help me out here.

Thanks guys!
Ingmar